# Does anybody in practice use environ directly to access environment variables?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

C standard library functions `getenv` and `setenv` can be used to access environment variables for a process.

In Linux, there is a documented global variable `environ` which holds environment variable value strings, so one could in principle use it directly and not use `getenv` and `setenv`.

My questions are:

1. Why is `environ` exposed and documented to the application programmer, where it seems unnecessary to do so?
2. Does any software now, or is future software likely, to use `environ` directly?

Comment: Guess: It's for compatibility reasons; the first unixes probably just used `environ`, because `setenv` and `getenv` didn't exist. And there may very well be some legacy programs which still do it that way.

Comment: This is a question for Linux kernel coders, more likely, and it is less likely to get a good answer here because it is broad and subject to personal opinion on the matter.

Comment: It's not just Linux, it's POSIX. `getenv` is standard C, but `environ main(,,envp) setenv unsetenv putenv` are only POSIX and there are non-POSIX implementations of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To answer your second question first,

   - Trivially, the `env` and `printenv` programs
     use `environ` to list the entire environment.
   - Most shells use `environ`
     to copy each environment variable into an exported shell variable. 
     (For example, in bash,
     commands like `set`, `export` and `declare` (with no arguments)
     will list the entire environment, along with non-exported variables.)
   - I’m not sure exactly how they handle it,
     but `su` and `sudo` pass a sanitized copy of the environment
     to the programs they invoke. 
     They might do it by iterating through the environment
     and deciding which variables to pass through, which to omit,
     and which to modify.
2. Why is `environ` exposed and documented to the application programmer?

   - Because some programs need it (see above).
   - The kernel has to pass the environment to the process (when it starts)
     somehow. 
     `getenv` and `setenv` (and a few other things)
     need to have access to the environment. 
     It’s tricky for the kernel
     to communicate to a library routine that isn’t active
     (i.e., to pass information to any part of the program
     other that the routine that is invoking the kernel). 
     It becomes doubly difficult given that,
     if you’re using static libraries,
     `getenv` and `setenv` won’t even be linked into your process image
     if the program doesn’t call them. 
     Using a global variable is the easiest solution.
   - Why did the designers/developers do it that way? 
     Why not? 
     The process owns its environment;
     it’s allowed to do whatever it want with it.

Comment: `awk` and `perl` also expose to scripts the entire set of envvars, as does Java to programs (though it _recommends_ people use Java's properties scheme a la `-Dname=value` instead).